# Draw squares along a randomly generated curve

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, bezier

I'm drawing a curved line from the left side of the screen to the right side of the screen and then drawing 5 squares along that curve in random positions.

[image]

The problem occurs if I change the y-value of the curved line's END-POINT.

**For example:** if the line starts on the left at point (0, 200) and ends on the right at (1000, 200) - meaning the y-coordinate has the exact same value at both points, everything is fine.
But if I change the **end-point's** y-value, everything gets thrown off - and I don't know how to properly compensate/calibrate for that change.

Working JSFiddle is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/soren74/sy61z35g/6/

```js
// Get the Canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



function init() {
  // INIT the starting (x, y) coordinate of the first line at the center of the left side of the canvas
  const startX = 0;

  const startY = canvas.height / 2;

  const endX = canvas.width;
  const endY = startY;

  // PROBLEM STARTS IF I DO THE FOLLOWING:
  // const endY = startY + 50;

  // Addind a random +1 or -1 var - to be used by the Control Points:
  let randall = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % 2;
  let deltaY = randall == 0 ? 1 : -1;

  // I. Set the Curved Line's CONTROL POINTS:
  // Control Point # 1:
  const cp1X = 150 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
  const cp1Y = startY - 250 * deltaY;
  console.log("\n>Control Pt. 1 = (" + cp1X + ", " + cp1Y + ")");

  // Control Point # 2:
  const cp2X = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
  const cp2Y = startY + 200 * deltaY;
  console.log("\n>Control Pt. 2 = (" + cp2X + ", " + cp2Y + ")");


  //
  //  II. DRAW the LINE
  // 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1X, cp1Y, cp2X, cp2Y, endX, endY);
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 8;
  ctx.shadowColor = "white";
  ctx.stroke();

  // Randomly place 5 squares along the curved Line:
  for (var squareCounter = 0; squareCounter < 5; squareCounter++) {
    const t = Math.random();
    const x = (1 - t) ** 3 * 0 + 3 * (1 - t) ** 2 * t * cp1X + 3 * (1 - t) * t ** 2 * cp2X + t ** 3 * canvas.width;
    const y = (1 - t) ** 3 * canvas.height / 2 + 3 * (1 - t) ** 2 * t * cp1Y + 3 * (1 - t) * t ** 2 * cp2Y + t ** 3 * canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(x - 4, y - 4, 8, 8);
  }


}

init();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in your formula for calculating the `y` coordinate, you don't use `endY`, and so changing the value of `endY` does not influence the result (while it *should*).

So remove all references to `canvas.height` and `canvas.width` in that formula and use the actual start/end coordinates:

```
const x = (1-t)**3*startX + 3*(1-t)**2*t*cp1X + 3*(1-t)*t**2*cp2X + t**3*endX;
const y = (1-t)**3*startY + 3*(1-t)**2*t*cp1Y + 3*(1-t)*t**2*cp2Y + t**3*endY;
```

```js
// Get the Canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function init() {
    // INIT the starting (x, y) coordinate of the first line 
    //    at the center of the left side of the canvas
    const startX = 0;
    const startY = canvas.height / 3;
    const endX = canvas.width;
    const endY = 2 * startY; // Different than startY

    // Addind a random +1 or -1 var - to be used by the Control Points:
    let deltaY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) * 2 - 1; 

    // I. Set the Curved Line's CONTROL POINTS:
    // Control Point # 1:
    const cp1X = 150 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200);
    const cp1Y = -50; // edited for this snippet only

    // Control Point # 2:
    const cp2X = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    const cp2Y = canvas.height + 50; // edited for this snippet only

    //  II. DRAW the LINE
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1X, cp1Y, cp2X, cp2Y, endX, endY);
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 8;
    ctx.shadowColor = "white";
    ctx.stroke();

    // Randomly place 5 squares along the curved Line:
    for(var squareCounter = 0; squareCounter < 5; squareCounter++) {
       const t = Math.random(), tt = 1 - t;
       const x = tt ** 3 * startX + 3 * tt * t * (tt * cp1X + t * cp2X) + t ** 3 * endX;
       const y = tt ** 3 * startY + 3 * tt * t * (tt * cp1Y + t * cp2Y) + t ** 3 * endY;
       ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
       ctx.fillRect(x - 4, y - 4, 8, 8);
    }
}

init();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black;}
body { margin: 0 }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="190"></canvas>
```